# Slow query using CONCAT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query using CONCAT and it became slow and I'm looking for a solution to perform it without using CONCAT to make it faster.

**A simplified version of the db** is here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iZunyu6QgQGMoyamsxg6rn/0

**The relation between tables are the following:**

- a quote_request has many quote_request_next_matches and many quote_matches
- a quote_request_next_match belongs to a quote_request and a partner
- a quote_match has one disposition_code

**Desired result: (Sample output can be found in the fiddle)** all the quote_requests that have quote_request_next_matches with partners that don't have quote_matches with disposition_codes with state = 7

The way it looks now is (it can also be found on the previous link):

```
  SELECT DISTINCT result.quote_request_id FROM (
    SELECT quote_requests.id as quote_request_id, quote_request_next_matches.partner_id as partner_id FROM quote_requests
      JOIN quote_request_next_matches ON quote_request_next_matches.quote_request_id = quote_requests.id
      JOIN partners ON quote_request_next_matches.partner_id = partners.id
      WHERE partners.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
    ) as  result LEFT JOIN quote_matches ON quote_matches.quote_request_id = result.quote_request_id
    WHERE CONCAT(result.quote_request_id, '_', result.partner_id) NOT IN (
      SELECT CONCAT(quote_requests.id, '_', partners.id)
        FROM quote_requests
        JOIN quote_request_next_matches ON quote_request_next_matches.quote_request_id = quote_requests.id
        JOIN partners ON quote_request_next_matches.partner_id = partners.id
        JOIN quote_matches ON CONCAT(quote_matches.quote_request_id, '_', quote_matches.partner_id)
          = CONCAT(quote_requests.id, '_', partners.id)
        JOIN disposition_codes ON disposition_codes.disposition_codable_id = quote_matches.id AND
          disposition_codes.disposition_codable_type = 'QuoteMatch' AND
          disposition_codes.state = 7
        WHERE partners.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
      )
))
```

The result from EXPLAIN ANALYZE is the following:

```
"Hash Join  (cost=16509.50..18165.56 rows=4428 width=196) (actual time=6003.057..6024.333 rows=4778 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: (quote_requests.id = quote_requests_1.id)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on quote_requests  (cost=0.00..1518.18 rows=52518 width=196) (actual time=0.008..16.382 rows=52518 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=16454.15..16454.15 rows=4428 width=8) (actual time=6003.032..6003.032 rows=4778 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 251kB"
"        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=16365.59..16409.87 rows=4428 width=8) (actual time=6001.665..6002.460 rows=4778 loops=1)"
"              Group Key: quote_requests_1.id"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=13593.07..16354.52 rows=4428 width=8) (actual time=152.262..5998.400 rows=5778 loops=1)""                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=13592.78..14029.46 rows=3957 width=8) (actual time=152.237..5976.368 rows=4780 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Index Only Scan using partners_pkey on partners  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (id = 15)"
"                                Heap Fetches: 1"
"                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=13592.64..13981.72 rows=3957 width=12) (actual time=152.230..5975.584 rows=4780 loops=1)"
"                                Hash Cond: (quote_request_next_matches.quote_request_id = quote_requests_1.id)"
"                                Join Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))"
"                                Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3121"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on quote_request_next_matches  (cost=0.00..368.31 rows=7913 width=8) (actual time=0.005..3.285 rows=7901 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: (partner_id = 15)"
"                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 9724"
"                                ->  Hash  (cost=1518.18..1518.18 rows=52518 width=8) (actual time=14.096..14.097 rows=52518 loops=1)"
"                                      Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2564kB"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on quote_requests quote_requests_1  (cost=0.00..1518.18 rows=52518 width=8) (actual time=0.002..7.403 rows=52518 loops=1)"
"                                SubPlan 1"
"                                  ->  Materialize  (cost=11417.98..14351.21 rows=84805 width=32) (actual time=0.016..0.132 rows=2507 loops=7901)"
"                                        ->  Merge Join  (cost=11417.98..13347.19 rows=84805 width=32) (actual time=128.971..136.558 rows=3123 loops=1)"
"                                              Merge Cond: ((concat(quote_matches_1.quote_request_id, '_', quote_matches_1.partner_id)) = (concat(quote_requests_2.id, '_', partners_1.id)))"
"                                              ->  Sort  (cost=8254.59..8259.94 rows=2143 width=16) (actual time=60.705..61.438 rows=8486 loops=1)"
"                                                    Sort Key: (concat(quote_matches_1.quote_request_id, '_', quote_matches_1.partner_id))"
"                                                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1047kB"
"                                                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=4410.60..8136.02 rows=2143 width=16) (actual time=22.182..31.475 rows=8486 loops=1)"
"                                                          Hash Cond: (disposition_codes.disposition_codable_id = quote_matches_1.id)"
"                                                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on disposition_codes  (cost=66.41..3786.20 rows=2145 width=4) (actual time=1.120..5.417 rows=8489 loops=1)"
"                                                                Recheck Cond: ((state = 7) AND ((disposition_codable_type)::text = 'QuoteMatch'::text))"
"                                                                Heap Blocks: exact=3265"
"                                                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_by_state_type_id  (cost=0.00..65.87 rows=2145 width=0) (actual time=0.765..0.765 rows=8489 loops=1)"
"                                                                      Index Cond: ((state = 7) AND ((disposition_codable_type)::text = 'QuoteMatch'::text))"
"                                                          ->  Hash  (cost=3609.64..3609.64 rows=58764 width=24) (actual time=20.985..20.985 rows=58764 loops=1)"
"                                                                Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3726kB"
"                                                                ->  Seq Scan on quote_matches quote_matches_1  (cost=0.00..3609.64 rows=58764 width=24) (actual time=0.011..11.648 rows=58764 loops=1)"
"                                              ->  Sort  (cost=3163.40..3183.18 rows=7913 width=16) (actual time=68.225..69.037 rows=7900 loops=1)"
"                                                    Sort Key: (concat(quote_requests_2.id, '_', partners_1.id))"
"                                                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 810kB"
"                                                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2174.80..2651.03 rows=7913 width=16) (actual time=30.825..43.602 rows=7901 loops=1)"
"                                                          ->  Index Only Scan using partners_pkey on partners partners_1  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.020..0.023 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                                Index Cond: (id = 15)"
"                                                                Heap Fetches: 1"
"                                                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=2174.66..2563.74 rows=7913 width=12) (actual time=30.761..37.113 rows=7901 loops=1)"
"                                                                Hash Cond: (quote_request_next_matches_1.quote_request_id = quote_requests_2.id)"
"                                                                ->  Seq Scan on quote_request_next_matches quote_request_next_matches_1  (cost=0.00..368.31 rows=7913 width=8) (actual time=0.015..2.847 rows=7901 loops=1)"
"                                                                      Filter: (partner_id = 15)"
"                                                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 9724"
"                                                                ->  Hash  (cost=1518.18..1518.18 rows=52518 width=8) (actual time=30.410..30.410 rows=52518 loops=1)"
"                                                                      Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2564kB"
"                                                                      ->  Seq Scan on quote_requests quote_requests_2  (cost=0.00..1518.18 rows=52518 width=8) (actual time=0.005..9.120 rows=52518 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Index Only Scan using index_quote_matches_on_quote_request_id on quote_matches  (cost=0.29..0.57 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=4780)"
"                          Index Cond: (quote_request_id = quote_requests_1.id)"
"                          Heap Fetches: 2672"
"Planning Time: 1.331 ms"
"Execution Time: 6024.699 ms"
```

Comment: I think sample data and desired results *in the question* would make it clearer what you want to do.  You seem to be explaining three tables but  the data model has five.

Comment: No need for concat: `where (result.quote_request_id, result.partner_id) NOT IN (SELECT quote_requests.id, '_', partners.id ...)` but typically rewriting that to a NOT EXISTS condition is faster. Same for the JOIN conditions, they don't need concat either

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you, I'll try this way.

Comment: The `JOIN quote_matches` in the sub-query seems suspicious as that is essentially again the condition of the NOT IN columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the comment from @a_horse_with_no_name was correct

No need for concat: where (result.quote_request_id, result.partner_id) NOT IN (SELECT quote_requests.id, '_', partners.id ...) but typically rewriting that to a NOT EXISTS condition is faster. Same for the JOIN conditions, they don't need concat either –

Thanks!